Can 3SAT karp reduces to Direct Hamiltonian Cycle remove buffer/extra node?
I learned 3SAT karp reduces to Direct Hamiltonian Cycle,
but in various resource I found, it all says it needs 3$k$+3 nodes per variable(row),
like here,

But I'm confused why the extra/buffer node is needed here,
I think we only need 2$k$+2 nodes per variable(row),
let Initial/End denotes every row's Initial and End note,
exclude them, counting remaining 2$k$ nodes start from index $0$,
so clause $k$ will connect to node 2$k$ and 2$k$+1,
If $x_a$ appears in clause $k$, then add direct edge 2$k$(at row $a$) --> clause $k$, add direct edge clause $k$ --> node 2$k$+1.
Even with 2$k$ + 2 nodes per row, the Direct Hamiltonian Cycle still can't do shenanigan
and jump from row $a$ to row $b$,
say clause $k$ has $x_a$ and $x_b$ in it,
say we have jump in cycle: $\text{Node}_{k,a}$ --> Clause $k$ --> $\text{Node}_{k,b}$,
then $\text{Node}_{k+1,a}$ will have to be connected from right to left since we used $\text{Node}_{k,a}$ and Clause $k$.
Then $\text{Node}_{k+2,a}$ (or end node at row a) ,if connect to $\text{Node}_{k+1,a}$, then it can't go back, since $\text{Node}_{k+2,a}$ (or end node at row a) has been used, and all of $\text{Node}_{k+1,a}$'s outgoing edge to $\text{Node}_{k,a}$ , Clause $k$,$\text{Node}_{k+2,a}$ can't be used,
so we don't have jumping rows Direct Hamiltonian Cycle which is doing shenanigan.
So I'm confused, why do we need 3$k$+3 nodes per row, instead we only need 2$k$+2 nodes per row, can we remove the extra/buffer nodes?

Label the variable row nodes left to right $1,2,3,4,\ldots$ and say $1$ and $2$ are allocated to Clause $A$ and $3$ and $4$ are allocated to clause $B$. Say clause $A$ has the variable negated, so there is an arrow $A\to1$ and $2\to A$. And similarly the variable is negated in clause $B$ so there's an arrow $B\to 3$ and $4\to B.$
The intention is that if you want to use this variable to satisfy clause $A$, you need to be traversing the row in the negative direction (from right to left) and go $$ \ldots\leftarrow 1\swarrow\dfrac{A}{}\nwarrow 2\leftarrow \ldots.$$ But say instead you traverse the row left to right as follows: $$\ldots \to 1\to 2\nearrow \dfrac{A \to\ldots\to  \mbox{(shenanigans)}\to \ldots\to B}{} \searrow 3 \to 4\to \ldots$$
and "illegally" visit $A.$ Having a buffer node between $2$ and $3$ prevents this possibility since you would need to skip the buffer node in the above scenario.
I'm not 100% sure the buffer nodes are strictly needed (I can't quickly come up with a working counterexample), but nor do I understand your argument that they aren't. I think you are assuming-in terms of the above labeling- that we exit at $1$ and then (because you needed to divert and do some shenanigans elsewhere?) can't come back to $2$ the usual way through the clause so need to come back through $3$, but as you can see above, that's not the situation they are intended for.

Your example is good. Using your example, when $A \to\ldots\to  \mbox{(shenanigans)}\to \ldots\to B$, the shenanigans will use at least 2 other nodes in other row, one A goes to, one comes back to B, which will break
future row travel. Of course this argument is very vague, hopefully it could be formalized.
